# Android Application (Samsung Galaxy Tab, 2.2) does not *sometimes* write to the DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite

We have an Android application running on Android 2.2 on the Samsung Galaxy Tab that writes data into the SQLite DB.

However, we find the following intermittent problem arising on *some* tablets.

1. The data is written into the DB. (No SQLiteExceptions being thrown; we are committing the transaction).
2. But the DB does not actually contain the data.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the application or clearing the application's data does not appear to make any difference at all.

When we then factory reset the handset and repeat the same procedure, it works just fine. This problem is not restricted to a given piece; all of us in my dev team have come across this intermittently.

However, I have not been able to reproduce the problem on any Android handsets (I tried on the HTC Desire, the HTC Desire HD, and the Samsung Galaxy S, all running Android 2.2), or on the emulator (running the Galaxy tab add-on).

I have a suspicion this may have something to do with a bug introduced by Samsung when they hacked Android 2.2. I was wondering if anybody else had encountered this problem, and if so, do you guys know of any less drastic measure than factory resetting the tablet?

Thanks,

Siddhu

Comment: Are you writing to the db from a single thread?

Comment: Is this on insert, update or delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are reports out there about Samsung misbehaving with Settings (not saving them). See [this Google issue](http://code.google.com/p/worksmart/issues/detail?id=416). The settings are also saved in the database. So my guess your issue is related, if not exactly the same.

Google for

> samsung settings not saved

for more hits.

We faced similar issues with our app in Samsung. Couldn't find an official statement from Samsung, so in the end documented to the users that this could happen in Samsung devices.